# Add entered value in a cell in a range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

it would be a follow up to the answer by Mike Steelson on that [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70527417/google-sheets-add-value-to-itself-in-same-cell). Their answer is great and works well, but for a single cell (in their example, cell C1).

I would like this, but for all the cells in a range. If it would be possible to apply this for say, C1:Z300, or a named range like "Contacts" it would be ideal for my specific case. I tried playing a bit with the script but I don't know enough.

So, in a range of cells, or a named range, whenever I enter a value in one cell, that value would be added to the old value of that specific cell.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. If you haven't done yet, please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers. If you need further help, please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts using conditions on onEdit triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName()=='Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart > 2 && e.range.columnStart < 27 && e.range.rowStart < 301){
    e.range.setValue(Number(e.value) + Number(e.oldValue));
  }
}
```